# Difference between variable bindings and variables?

Tags: rust, nomenclature

Over my time using Rust, I’ve seen some people call them variables whilst others call them variable bindings - or even bindings as a short way of referring to it.

In the Rust book, [it’s stated](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/variable-bindings.html#patterns):

> In many languages, a variable binding would be called a variable, but Rust’s variable bindings have a few tricks up their sleeves. For example the left-hand side of a let statement is a ‘pattern’, not a variable name.

Later in the book, they go on referring to variable bindings as either bindings or variables. The same I’ve noticed here on *Stackoverflow* - it seems as though they’e used interchangably.

The question is whether or not there a time when referring to bindings as variables is more correct than the latter? I would assume both are different words for the more correct term - variable bindings - should you follow the words from their book. I’m confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [variable binding](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/variable-bindings.html) is a [statement](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#statements) that binds a variable to a name; in the statement

```
let x = 1;
```

The whole statement is the variable binding and `x` is the name the variable gets bound to. After this statement you may refer to `x` as a *variable* or a *binding* (but not a *variable binding*).

The fragment you brought up just emphasizes the fact that in Rust you can do all kinds of stuff with variable bindings since `let` statements are subject to pattern matching, e.g.

```
let (a, b, c, s) = (1u8, 2usize, 3i32, "foo");
```

Assigns 4 variables of different types at once.

**Edit**: there might be a reason why *binding* is such a popular term with Rust even though *variable* is a much more established term in programming; since in Rust bindings are immutable by default, it might be weird for people without a programming background to call them **variable**s.

Comment: I always thought "binding" instead of "assignment" had to do with Rust's ownership semantics. Basically let s =       "foo".to_string() binds the right hand value to its owner, s.